# Deadlock after transferring to another IIS Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2000, deadlock

We transferred an old ASP application from Windows 2000 to Windows 2008 R2 to upgrade its performance. We only transfer the ASP application, the database is still the same. After successful transfer, the users of the web application encounters a deadlock from SQL.

> Transaction [Process ID XX] was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

So what we did is to transfer it again to a newly installed Windows 2000 but still the error appears.

I am thinking that maybe there are things that I need to configure on IIS, since nothing has changed except for the web server but I can't figure out what I've missed.

Comment: what version of SQL Server or you running?

Comment: SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to capture what is causing the deadlocks and then make the necessary adjustments moving forward. One way to do this is to use trace flags to write to the Sql Server error log.  If not already in place, there are two trace flags that can be enabled to capture more information in the log: 1204 and 1222. 1204 lists the information by node; 1222 lists it by process & resource. You can enable both at the same time by running the command: DBCC TRACEON (1204, 1222).  Then, you can look through the error log using sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'XXXX' to pin down the information.

Comment: If they are running SQL Server 2000 then trace flag 1222 will not be available.